# Is there a way to register whole module in Dropwizard/Jersey?

Tags: java, jersey, java-8, dropwizard

I know I can register resources in dropwizard like 
`environment.jersey().register(new MyResource());`

But if I have like 10+ or 20+ resource classes, it seems extremely inefficient to write 20+ lines. Is there a way to register all the classes in a module.

Googling for it reveal much. Any pointers to either docs or examples would be helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection

Comment: An alternative way, if you add guicey to your setup, you get guice support + package scan + so-called installers that not only register the resources for you, but also all the filters and features that you may or may not have. https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey

Comment: good options :thumbsup:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use package scanning:

```
environment.jersey().packages(Class1.class.getPackage().getName(), "my.package2")
```

The documentation from io.dropwizard.jersey.setup.JerseyEnvironment:

```
/**
 * Adds array of package names which will be used to scan for components. Packages will be
 * scanned recursively, including all nested packages.
 *
 * @param packages array of package names
 */
public void packages(String... packages)
```